# Leur absence / manque de désir de communiquer / communication avec moi est évidente

Tags: sens, expressions

Bonjour,

> Plus les minutes s'écoulent, plus leur **absence** de désir de **communiquer**
> avec moi est évidente.
>
> Plus les minutes s'écoulent, plus leur **manque** de désir de communiquer
> avec moi est évidente.
>
> Plus les minutes s'écoulent, plus leur absence de désir de
> **communication** avec moi est évidente.

Est-il possible de remplacer "absence" par "manque" et "communiquer avec moi" par "communication avec moi" ?

Comment: Tout dépend du type de relation envisagé autour du mot pivot *désir* : — qui peut être *absent* sans *leur manquer* (ce n'est pas leur problème) — qui peut *leur manquer* sans être [vraiment] *absent* (ils n'en ont pas pour moi, ou ils sont incapables d'en avoir), —  *Désir de communiquer* se passe dans l'instant présent (plutôt sur un point précis ou dans le cadre de la rencontre) — *désir de communication* “en principe” avec autrui, avec vous en particulier (rejet de tout échange).  …

Comment: … il y a sûrement d'autres nuances ou *manque* et *absence* sont synonymes  et peuvent être évoqués conjointement pour “enfoncer le clou” … tout cela est soumis à l'inspiration de l'auteur :-) .

Comment: @Personne Merci. :) _qui peut être absent sans leur manquer (ce n'est pas leur problème) — qui peut leur manquer sans être [vraiment] absent_ --- C'est vrai.

Comment: Quel est le motif pour clore cette question qui repose sur la signification réelle des mots, leur usage et le moyen d'évoquer ce que leur juxtaposition révèle dans une phrase construite correctement, quelle règle absurde interdirait à un francophile l'accès aux subtilités de la rédaction d'une pensée, d'une intuition, d'une intention … toute la créativité et la richesse d'une langue difficile à apprendre ?